# Changing Uid Using MFRC522 Via Arduino Error

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, rfid

Well, I' ve just bought and recieved a MFRC522 rfıd module and done to much research on it. After watching several videos, I sorted out a library for using this module via arduino. 
You can click the first link below to be navigated to Miguel Balboa' s github page including the library that I mentioned and example codes written by him using that library. Though I' ve downloaded the zip file, ran such codes as dumpInfo, read and write, unfortunetely I couldn' t made "changeUid" example work. U can reach this example code via the link below as well. My connection is true, I' m sure bout' that[image: Connection is same an shown in code]  If anybody had faced this kind of problem or knows the solution, their answers will be enough satisfying for me I guess... (By the way, error was this sentance: Are you sure this is a uid changeable card -I was sure, my card was a Mifare 1K card- failure, the card responded as NAK)

**link: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for UID changeable card. The kit included this RFID reader just had a normal RFID card and keychain. You will probably have to buy it yourself. I bought it from aliexpress but I don' t remember which seller. Good Luck! (I mean who read this...)